# How to select from result query and display records on another page?

Tags: php, mysql

i've a page that shows records from a query into a div per record, ie:

```
on page showresult.php:
-----------div 1-----------
ID | Hotel 1 | address | infos 
-----------div 2----------
ID | Hotel 2 | address | infos
```

Well, now what i'd like to do is  to select one of these clicking on it and shows more infos about the selected hotel (ie hotel 2) into another page, like:

```
on page showmoresults.php
----------div selected hotel 2-----------
ID | Hotel 2 | address | infos | details | address | city | etc..
```

How to do the trick ?

Thanks in advance!

PS: i currently use sessions

Comment: i tried to make a link for each div but i'm totally stucked

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple we take a example. we have a link text "Hotel 2" we make the link look like this "a" tag with href="/hotel/2"> and text is Hotel2 and handle this is in your controller and process with id 2. Like MySql query. @hotel = select * from hotels where id = 2 .
and all info in in @hotel

Comment: thanks man but i guess how to pass the relative hotel's ID to the second page. Do i use to send the relative ID to an hidden input inside a form and to GET/POST recevice it into the second page that makes the query like select * from hotels where id = 2  ?

Comment: ok i figured out using links and passing the hotel id via get to another page where i make the second select with the id get and shows the results in a table.